# How to define Rspec custom matcher for its(:field)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macros, rspec

I want to declare custom matcher for Rspec 2

I am using `rspec 2.13` and `rails 3.2.13`.

I have tried to write something like this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_present do |expected|
  match do
    expected !be_empty
  end
end
```

but when I use this in spec, it doesn't works
Failures:

```
  1) NewsletterMailer.send_newsletter_to_groups from 
     Failure/Error: its(:from) { should be_present }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Spec code:

```
describe NewsletterMailer do

  describe '.send_newsletter_to_emails' do
    let(:user) { create(:admin) }
    let(:user2) { create(:user) }
    subject { NewsletterMailer.send_newsletter_to_emails(newsletter.id, "#{user.email}, #{user2.email}") }

    its(:to) { should == [user.email, user2.email] }
    its(:from) { should be_present }
    its(:subject) { should be }
  end
```

**Edit:**

I want to have reverse of logic like this:

```
its(:from) { should_not be_nil }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_present do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual && actual.present?
  end
end
```

---

Looks like this helper already exists in Rspec.

I just reinvented wheel. But I will still let this answer and don't delete this post.

It will be tip for developers, how to declare custom matcher without parameter eg.

`be_something_special`

Comment: This will only work if `present?` is defined, and if that's the case then rspec's built-in predicate matchers will already provide a `be_present` matcher.

Comment: If `present?` helper is not available, you can do something like this : `actual && !actual.empty?`.

Comment: lol, you're right. Rspec already provides this matcher, looks like I duplicated code :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need a custom matcher at all here. Wouldn't

`its(:from) { should be }`

work for you?

See here:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers#be-matcher

`obj.should be       # passes if obj is not nil`

**Update:**

Since apparently the question is how to write a custom matcher for an existing predicate `present?`, then the answer is: rspec already provides that, and there is still no need to write a custom matcher.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-3/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers

For any predicate `#foo?` on an object, you can just write `should be_foo`. Rspec will even define matchers for predicates that start with "has" like `has_foo?` with a more natural syntax, so that you can just write `should have_foo`.

Comment: This will only check if `field` is not `nil`. eg. `string` have `size == 0` and this return `true`.

Comment: That's correct but you said you wanted the behavior of `should_not be_nil`, right? If you meant is that want to check that it's both non-nil and has length > 0 *and* if you're using Rails you can do `its(:from) { should_not be_blank }`